# use url pdf instead of file pdf in R

Tags: r

I'm using the following line to import text from a PDF in `R`

```
uri <- sprintf("name.pdf", system.file(file.path("doc", "tm.pdf"),
                package = "tm"))
```

However, I would like to use directly the URL from where I'm getting the PDF in the first argument, instead of the PDF file in my hard disk.

Comment: You can use [download.file](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/download.file.html) to download a file locally

Comment: So simple, thanks! I was stuck on changing the argument and couldn't think the obvious way!

Comment: BTW the code you posted isn't related to the question, it's only a line copied from the `tm` packages samples.  Checking the documentation of the `tm` package I see that `readPDF` accepts a URL - you can already do what you are asking. *Do* you have a specific problem?

Comment: there is an even simpler way. Pass the `uri` to `readPDF`. The code you posted creates a URI from a local file, you *don't* need it.

Comment: I managed to do using the `download.file` command, but not as you're saying. Could you please give an example using the URL in `readPDF`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that the sample in readPDF's documentation uses this line to create a local file URL:

```
uri <- sprintf("file://%s", system.file(file.path("doc", "tm.pdf"), package = "tm"))
```

<s>You don't need to do this for an `ftp` or `http` url, just pass the URL as it is. `readPDF` accepts URLs *only*, so even local file paths have to be converted to a URI.</s>

You can simply write:

```
uri <- "http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/tm.pdf"
```

To get the `tm` package's documentation, then go on to read it with `readPDF`:

```
uri <- "http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/tm.pdf"
pdf <- readPDF(control = list(text = "-layout"))(elem = list(uri = uri),
                                               language = "en",
                                               id = "id1")
```

Even though `readPDF` expects a URL, at least in Windows you can only use it with a local file. `readPDF` essentially acts as a wrapper over external commands, so the URI is passed *as-is* to `pdftotext` (for xpdf) or whichever command is used by the engine you specify. Unless *that* command understands URLs, it will fail with a warning.

The only real alternative is to download the file locally with `download.file` then read it with `readPDF`:

```
uri <- "http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/tm.pdf"
download.file(uri,"tm.pdf",method="internal",mode="wb")
pdf <- readPDF(control = list(text = "-layout"))(elem = list(uri = "tm.pdf"),
                                               language = "en",
                                               id = "id1")
content(pdf)[1:13]
```

I am able to use a relative file path because the `uri` parameter is passed as is, it's not treated as a URI at all. I was able to pass `"h:\\documents\\tm.pdf"` and `"h:/documents/tm.pdf"`as well.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still a bit confused. After doing this, how can I see the content of the PDF? Basically I want to get all the text from the PDF.

Comment: That's shown in the `readPDF` documentation, in the same sample as the rest of the code. After reading the file you can use the `content(pdf)[1:13]` to read a specific portion of the file

Comment: I get `NA`s.. The thing is that when I run the code you pasted, I get warnings, so I think nothing is stored. Any ideas?

Comment: If I put to `uri` the name of my file in my local directory it works, if I use the link it doesn't.. I can't find why

Comment: After all, I think you can't use a URI, at least in Windows. `readPDF` passes the uri as is to an external command. `xpdf` at least only works with local files so this causes an error. I haven't found any example that *explicitly* uses a URL, only hints, references and falling back to ... straight calls to `pdftotext.exe`.

Comment: No problem at all, using `download.file` first is good enough. Many thanks!